# Prove that there is no continuous function $f : \Bbb R → \Bbb R $ such that $f = χ_I$ almost everywhere on $\Bbb R$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $I = [0,1]$ and $χ_I : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ be the characteristic function on $I$. Prove that there is no continuous function $f : \Bbb R → \Bbb R $ such that $f = χ_I$ almost everywhere on $\Bbb R$.
[Note that for every $n ∈ \Bbb N$, one can construct a continuous function $g : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ such
that $m\{x∈\Bbb R:|g(x)\neq χ_I(x)|\}< 1/n$]

It was given as a hint.

Now I was trying to solve (Actually I have found some other ways to do it) in a way that $m(\{x| g(x) \neq f(x)\})=0$ so for any $n \in \Bbb N$ $\exists N_n\in \Bbb N$ s.t $m(\{x: |g(x) - f(x)|>1/n\})<1/N_n$.

Now I wanted to rule out the continuity of $g$.

Here at $x=0$ I shall get $x_n \to 0$ from the negative side

So, $|χ_I(x_n)-χ_I(0)| \leq |χ_I(x_n)-g(x_n)|+|g(x_n)-g(0)|+|g(0)-χ_I(0)|$. But the thing is even if $χ_I(x_n)\neq g(x_n)$ in a countably many numbers then the measure may still be zero. So how to proceed next?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $f=\chi_I$ almost everywhere and $f$ is continuous, you must have for example

$$f\lvert_{(-\infty,0)}=0$$

since if for some $x \in (-\infty,0)$ you have $f(x)\neq0$, then from continuity you must have that $f(x)\neq0$ on some ball $B_\epsilon(x)$. But then $f$ differs from $\chi_I$ on a set that is not a measure zero set (namely $B_\epsilon(x) \cap (-\infty,0)$), which is a contradiction.

The same argument shows that

$$f\lvert_{(0,1)}(x)=1$$

These two statements are incompatible with $f$ being continuous at $0$.